# VueJS - How can call function when transition page on App.vue

Tags: animation, vue.js, vue-router

i try to make animation when i change transition page, my App.Vue is like this :

```
<transition name="test" v-on:before-leave="leave"
      v-on:leave="leave"
      v-on:after-leave="leave"
      v-on:leave-cancelled="leave"
      :duration="{ enter: 0, leave: 800 }">
        <router-view />
</transition>
```

When i click on button in Home.vue, I would like to start a function that is in my home route before my new page is load..
I want to apply function in my App.vue on beforeLeave event

Thanks,

Comment: Is `v-on:before-leave` your custom directives?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks all of directives i use is describe here

Comment: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4qnjvmwz9?from-embed) might help you. If not, Let me know. I can create one for you/

Comment: Yep but in your example you don't have <router-view> and the event is in components not in App.vue because me i render my route in App.vue and i don't know if i can passing props to router view for detect leave event on my page

Comment: Here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zrj5wx7nm3) with `router-view`. let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your example but i think i must use this : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html but i don't know how i can use it in my component

Comment: Its solved with https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html